# Back button takes me to home screen instead of previous activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to add a login/register activities to my app, but I'm new to Android dev, so I'm not sure the right way I should be doing this.

The current logic I've got is:

App opens to `MainActivity`, `MainActivity` immediately launches the `LoginActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        startActivity(
            Intent(baseContext, LoginActivity::class.java).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
        )
        finish()
    }
}
```

The `LoginActivity` has a login form and register/forgot password buttons.  When the register button is pressed, I launch the RegisterActivity:

```
private fun handleRegisterClick() {
    startActivity(Intent(baseContext, RegisterActivity::class.java))
}
```

The problem I'm running into is when I press the Android back button in `RegisterActivity`, it takes me to the home screen instead of back to `LoginActivity`. Why is this happening?

Comment: you can override the onBackpressed() method and check backstack.

Comment: Why you are using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`?

Comment: @ADM Originally I thought it would keep the back button from sending the user back to the blank `MainActivity`, but I realize now that's what `finish` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've added the line `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)` which is applied to the Intent you are starting `LoginActivity` and not the Activity you are currently in. The call you've made to `finish()` will ensure that the `MainActivity` is not there to be navigated back to when you press the back button.

Comment: Ah. I should have thought to remove that flag after I noticed it wasn't doing what I wanted (I was trying to use it in place of `finish` before I knew about `finish`). Removing the `addFlags` call fixes the issue.

Comment: You've gone CodeBlind

Comment: Too early for that. Let's call it not enough coffee.

Comment: After too many search. I got this answer and it works in my condition. Thanks!